# Empty or malformed authorisation header. Please provide an API key or session token. 400 bad request error

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-400, bad-request, clarifai

I am building a food detection application and I have literally tried everything to remove this error! I get a 400 bad request error when I paste a url.

This is the status code which shows the error:

```
> {"status":{"code":11102,"description":"Invalid request","details":"Empty or malformed authorization header. Please provide an API key or session token.","req_id":"7d399e162bb943f5848960862ccedbe9"}}
```

My App.js is this (have not included the import part and the api key):

```
      const app = new Clarifai.App({
          apiKey: "MY API KEY",
        });
        
        const particleOptions = {
          particles: {
            number: {
              value: 100,
              density: {
                enable: true,
                value_area: 800,
              },
            },
          },
        };
        
        class App extends Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              input: "",
              imageUrl: "",
              showModal: false,
              foodIngredients: [],
            };
          }
    
      onInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
      };
    
         onButtonSubmit = () => {
                this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input, showModal: true });
                app.models
                  .predict(
                    {
                      model_id: " bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7",
                      version_id: "dfebc169854e429086aceb8368662641",
                    },
                    this.state.input
                  )
                  .then((response) => {
                    console.log("hi", response);
                    if (response) {
                      fetch("http://localhost:3000/image/", {
                        method: "put",
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                          url: this.state.input,
                        }),
                      })
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((response) => {
                          //response ingredient array
                          if (response.length <= 0) {
                            return this.setState({
                              input: "",
                              foodIngredients: [response],
                            });
                          } else {
                            this.setState({
                              input: "",
                              foodIngredients: response,
                            });
                          }
                        });
                    }
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.setState({ imageUrl: "" });
                  });
              };

  onModalShow = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false, foodIngredients: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const { input, imageURL, showModal, foodIngredients } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Particles className="particles" params={particleOptions} />
        <div>
          <Logo />
          <ImageLinkForm
            urlInput={this.onInputChange}
            text={input}
            buttonClick={this.onButtonSubmit}
          />
          <FoodRecognition
            url={imageURL}
            show={showModal}
            canceled={this.onModalShow}
            foodIngredients={foodIngredients}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please let me know if I need to add or change anything.

**UPDATE**
I get a new error when I change the .predict

```
app.models
      .predict(
        Clarifai.FOOD_MODEL,
        // {
        //   model_id: " bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7",
        //   version_id: "dfebc169854e429086aceb8368662641",
        // },
        this.state.input
      )
```

Error:

```
App.js:55 PUT http://localhost:3000/image/ 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: The code you show does not show a request to `https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/searches` which is where the error is from.  Please show the code that corresponds to the actual error.

Comment: And, include code IN your question as text (not as an image), properly  formatted as code.   This is a baseline procedure for posting questions on Stackoverflow.  Code should never be in images here on Stackoverflow for all sorts of reasons.  It can't be searched.  People trying to help can't copy/paste into answers, external images have a habit of disappearing over time rendering the question useless as a long term reference, etc...

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the question (code) as text.

Comment: When I press my app.js in the console. It takes me to .catch((err). So I just pasted the entire code thinking it would help people understand what iam trying to do.

Comment: The only actual HTTP request you show directly in the code is to localhost which does not correspond to the error message.  Is the error coming from `app.models.predict().catch(...)`?  Is that the `.catch()` where the error shows?  If so, then it's coming from inside the Clarifai library I guess so the issue will be in the parameters you're passing to that.

Comment: Are you using a real and valid API key in place of what your code shows as `apiKey: "MY API KEY",`?

Comment: Yes, its a valid key. I just  didn't want to post my Api key publicly so just wrote MY API KEY there.

Comment: status: {code: 11100, description: "Bad request format",…}, models: []}
models: []
status: {code: 11100, description: "Bad request format",…}
code: 11100
description: "Bad request format"
details: "Query must contain at least one of 'name', 'type', or 'model_type_id'. Check your request fields." --- I am not too sure if its the parameters but this is what the network preview shows.

Answer (score 0):

- You are using the deprecated Javascript REST SDK: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript
- Make sure to use the NodeJS gRPC client: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-nodejs-grpc or directly call the Clarifai API: https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/data/create-get-update-delete (see "Javascript (REST)" snippets)

Comment: The problem is that I am getting a response in the console. But I cannot display the image on the website when I fetch the URL

Comment: I am getting two errors. One : `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot PUT /images</pre>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: The other:    `fetch("http://localhost:3000/images",` on this line